# How to use secondary VGA device for TTYs

Tags: tty, graphics, display-settings

I have a machine (a virtual XEN DomU, but I don't think it matters) with two video cards. I would like to display the TTYs on the monitor connected to the secondary video card (i.e., not the display that the BIOS shows up on). I don't know if it matters, but the machine is running Arch Linux. When I booted the Arch installation media, the boot screen showed up on the primary monitor, but once I chose what I wanted to boot (x86_64 Arch) the startup "script" did some probing and detected my secondary VGA device and displayed the TTYs only on that device and not on the primary device. Ideally, I would like to mimic this behaviour such that if the secondary device is removed, I would still have access to the TTYs.