# How to get tty to display on another monitor (using nvidia drivers)

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, tty, framebuffer

I am trying to have the tty (at boot) to display on a secondary monitor than what it currently starts on, or even better - to have multiple tty's running at once on different displays, as is described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt)
(In section C3) after trying to work this out and running:

> cat /proc/fb

and getting an output of

> 0 EFI VGA

I have to say that I have no ideas what to do, whatsoever.

Should I have different monitors as different framebuffers? Is that viable? Should I have it all as one framebuffer?

Comment: Are you running the nvidia closed source driver, or nouveau? If the first, maybe try nouveau, it's closer to how the "usual" framebuffer drivers work.

Comment: I'm running the proprietary one, but need that one for better performance - video editing/games etc.

Comment: With nouveau , it just displays it on all monitors at once with the same thing. Even getting it like that with the nvidia driver would be great!

Comment: I want that too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157044/how-to-use-secondary-vga-device-for-ttys what happens when you boot from the Arch ISO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nouveau:

Judging from the [Forcing modes](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/KernelModeSetting/) section, and the [drm_fb_helper.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/nouveau/linux-2.6/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c) source linked from there, it looks like you need to write a custom driver and override the `drm_fb_helper_single_add_all_connectors` with your own routine to get multiple framebuffers for different outputs.

Not easy to do if you are not a programmer.

(BTW, a *framebuffer* is a piece of memory that stores the pixels you see on your monitor(s). The `/dev/fb` device(s) expose that piece of memory to linux programs, and the *modesetting part* (also *kernel modesetting*, KMS) instructs the hardware to display that particular framebuffer with a particular resolution and frequencies.)

Comment: Is there any way to add a monitor as a separate frabebuffer device with the nvidia driver?

Comment: No idea. AFAIK "twinview" etc. only works for X, and not on the fb level, but my working knowledge about the nvidia driver is really outdated. I'm not even sure if nvidia now exposes a `/dev/fb` device, it didn't back then when I used it.

Comment: Only the VGA one, from cat /proc/fb in the first post - I was hoping there was a way to add or change which one it was, without just changing the cables around, as that would be very inconvenient

Comment: It's possible that this is just the default VGA fb device, not the nvidia driver one. If that is correct, the fb device and the nvidia driver are totally unrelated, and you won't be able to use different outputs or other features of your graphics card that are not standard VGA.