# Xen: Graphical output on domU after secondary GPU passthrough

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, xen, radeon, fglrx

I have done a secondary GPU passthrough to a Linux domU, but I don't know how to output Xorg from the secondary GPU.

The dom0 is using an Intel integrated graphics card. I am passing through an AMD 6450 to domU, as it there were two mentions of it here:

https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_VGA_Passthrough_Tested_Adapters

Short list of what I did:

1. Enabled VT-d in motherboard BIOS
2. Added `intel_iommu=on` to dom0 GRUB
3. Blacklisted modules of GPU and it's audio subsystem
4. `modprobe xen-pciback`
5. `xl pci-assignable-add _______` for both GPU and it's audio subsystem
6. Added the two PCI IDs to the Xen configuration file: `pci = [ '_____', '_____' ]`
7. Booted and installed Linux in the domU

When I boot, after the above steps, I get one error message:
`libxl: error: libxl_pci.c:1151:libxl__device_pci_reset: The kernel doesn't support reset from sysfs for PCI device 0000:01.00.0`
Despite the above error, when I run `lspci -nnk` on the domU, it shows the GPU and audio sub-device, including these lines:
`Kernel driver in use: radeon`
`Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel`
Also, of course, a line for the primary domU virtual GPU:
`Kernel driver in use: cirrus`

Then, if I connect a VGA or DVI cable from the passed through GPU to the monitor, the monitor stays on (green power button) with a dark grey screen. Whereas 
usually, when the monitor detects no input, it just goes straight to standby (orange power button). So there is some kind of GPU output.

If I `startx` and run `xrandr` through VNC, there doesn't seem to be any sign of the physical monitor, it seems there is only the virtualized 
VNC/cirrus monitor.

If I add `gfx_passthru=1` to the configuration file, it always fails at boot. The first error message that appears when I add `gfx_passthru=1` is:
`libxl: error: libxl_dm.c:1302:libxl__build_device_model_args_new: unable to detect required gfx_passthru_kind`

Before I ever used virtualisation, to switch output from primary/secondary graphics card to the other, I would usually just change the settings in the 
BIOS, and Linux would follow. So Xorg + domU is very different territory for me.

Does anyone know how I can output Xorg through the secondary GPU in the domU, after this point ? Various GPU passthrough guides online only cover 
Windows.

**UPDATE**

After StrongBad's response, I have moved from an Arch domU to a Debian 8.8 from the Debian wiki domU, as `fglrx` is not in the official Arch repos anymore.

However, unlike the Arch domU, the Debian domU has no mysterious dark grey monitor output with always-on green power button, when the passed through GPU is connected to the monitor.

Nonetheless, I did the following:

1. Installed `fglrx`
2. Ran `sudo aticonfig --initial`
3. Added the four lines to `/etc/xorg.conf` [from the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary#configure)

However, when I run `startx` from a VNC TTY, it just crashes. The first error message in `Xorg.0.log` states:
`(EE) fglrx(0): Failed to open CMMQS connection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are pretty far along. I more or less successfully got secondary VGA passthrough working with Xen 4.4.0 (and a few later versions). I had trouble with version 4.7, but never really tried to debug it. If I recall correctly, in my working system, I also got an error like:

```
libxl: error: libxl_pci.c:1151:libxl__device_pci_reset: The kernel doesn't support reset from sysfs for PCI device 0000:01.00.0
```

While trying to get secondary passthrough working I asked a [question on the Xen list](https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2014-06/msg00107.html). I had two issues that I could never solve. The first is that the [TTYs are on the primary device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157044/how-to-use-secondary-vga-device-for-ttys) so I cannot see any boot messages and can only use an X session. The second issue was I could only use the proprietary catalyst drivers. It looks like you are trying to use the Radeon drivers, so that might be your issue.

I am pretty sure `gfx_passthru=1` is only for primary passthrough so you probably do not want it. I asked on the Xen mailing list what the difference between primary and secondary passthrough, apart from a lot of pain, is. The [response](https://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2014-05/msg00002.html) was:

> The only advantage of passing the interface as primary (and FWIW I have
>   never actually seen this work) is that in that case you get to see the SeaBIOS POST screen and the domU OS boot progress before it loads the GPU

Comment: OK I will give `fglrx` a try and see what happens. I hadn't thought of that making a difference, thank you for the tip !